# Conditional formating with power of two; bold or color

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How do I make conditional statement in the input line to change color based on the cell value is a power or two or not?

For example, if the cell value on A3 is a power of two i want it to return bold or a colorized value, if it is not a power of two then i want it to leave it as it is.

Comment: "in the input line" - meaning in the formula rather than using [conditional formatting](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula formats the cell to `Heading 1` (bold) for powers of 2.

```
=3+5+STYLE(IF(MOD(LOG(CURRENT();2);1)=0;"Heading 1";"Default"))
```

Explanation:

- `= 3 + 5` is an example cell value that results in power of two.
- `+ STYLE` applies a style. `STYLE` returns zero, so adding zero will not change a numeric result.
- `LOG(x,2)` tests whether the value is a power of 2. If it is, then `MOD(x,1)` should be zero.
- `CURRENT()` is the current value of the cell. Be careful not to use this more than once in a formula.

Documentation: [STYLE](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_STYLE_function)